# how can I call background-image as <img src>

Tags: html

background image will not display. It will display as an img src. So how can I call background-image as

```
<body>
<div id="page" style="background- image:url(https://storage.blob.core.windows.net/name/image.png)">
```

Comment: Have you tried without the space in `background- image`. Like so: `background-image`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The style is

> background-image

Not background- image

And you refer to a 'https' link which will return no picture at all
(I tried to your link, it gives an error)

**EDIT**

The https means that the url you access is securised, which means that you can't access its content without login in.
Thus, the picture you wanna access in secured. You can perhaps see it if you login, your visitor wont because they cant access it.

If you want a picture to be background, either link it from your website

```
background-image:url(images/bg.jpg);
width:100%;
height:100%;
```

Either take the url from a website WITHOUT https

I recommend you to use either google for pictures, or wallbase.cc which is a good one too
And as a little advice i can give you:

```
background-image:url(YOUR URL HERE);
background-size:cover;
```

The `background-size:cover` will make your background always the right size if you change your window's width and height, it's perfect for smaller/bigger screen

Comment: I need to call 'https' as an img src?

Answer (score 0):

```
<div class="row bg-image mt-3 text-white" 
     style="background-image:url('/images/web-1.png');
            height:40%;
            background-size:cover;
            background-repeat:no-repeat" 
</div>

if you are using Bootstrap, the above html should show the image specified in the url(<path>)
```

Answer (score -1):

### 2 issues found there:

1. `background -image`  doesn't work as CSS. The right property is `background-image` (without space);
2. Background image in a blank div will never show any background - you need to **1)** add some content OR **2)** set the size of your div.

As this, the right way for doing that is:

**HTML**

```
<div id="page"></div>
```

**CSS**

```
#page {
    background-image: url('http://gianlucaguarini.com/canvas-experiments/jQuery.BlackAndWhite/files/big-img.jpg');
    width: 800px;
    height: 533px;
}
```

[**JSFiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/Wes24/)